# How can I apply simpleExpandableListAdapter or similar thing to ListView in ListFragment

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-fragments

I am working with ListFragment and want to make a difficult list, which has sublists  and don't know how I can do it((
Some code:

```
public class CarsOfBrandFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        String[] s = {"colorName"};
        int[] k = {R.id.groupname};
        String[] s1 = new String[]{"shadeName", "rgb"};
        int[] k1 = new int[]{R.id.childname, R.id.rgb};
        SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), createGroupList(),
            R.layout.grouprow, s, k, createChildList(), R.layout.childrow, s1, k1);
        setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
    }
```

setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) in android.support.v4.app.ListFragment cannot be applied to (android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter)

Comment: I would advice to take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051050/expandablelistfragment-with-loadermanager-for-compatibility-package

Comment: I filed a feature request for this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20973 please vote for it!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader#comment13750623_10611927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I decided this by explicit indicating of `ExapndableListView` - yes I changed usual ListView on Expandable, and using `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` instead of `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just set it on the ListView itself?

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list);
lv.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
```

Comment: no, compiling error. Obviously this adapter is not compatible with ListView. Maybe is there another way?

Comment: i wrote above: setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter) in android.support.v4.app.ListFragment cannot be applied to (android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter)