# Using ExpandableListFragment from arne.jans never triggers onListItemClickListener event

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I wanted to use an ExpandableListView for my Fragment but since it's not native, I used this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6193434/969881 containing an ExpandableListFragment class extending Fragment.

This works well, I declare my Fragment like this :

```
public class MyExpListFragment extends ExpandableListFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
        getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        groupData,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
        new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
        childData,
        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
        new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
    );

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

...

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.i("TAG", "Item selected");
}



}
```

But unfortunately the onListItemClick is never triggered. Do you have any clue ?

I also have these problems :

- the onGroupCollapsed, onGroupExpand, and onChildClick are not Overrided methods (e.g : The method onChildClick(ExpandableListView, View, int, int, long) of type ExpandableListFragment must override a superclass method) I wonder why because my class extends ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.
- The onGroupCollapsed, onGroupExpand and onChildClick are never triggered as well, probably because they are not seen as methods overriding superclass methods.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this one.

I use an ExpandableListView as a private parameter of my fragment like this :

```
private ExpandableListView elv;
```

Then, after my fragment is created, I link my elv to the current ExpandableListView created by my expandableListFragment :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    elv = getExpandableListView();
}
```

Then I can trigger any event of my ExpandableListView just like this :

```
elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {    
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Group number " + groupPosition + " is clicked "); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my superclass of ExpandableListFragment i add these methods

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("LocalListFragment", "onActivityCreated");
        super.onContentChanged();
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        Map<String, String> childmap = (Map<String, String>) mAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        String c = (String)childmap.get(CHILD);

        Map<String, String> groupmap = (Map<String, String>) mAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
        String g = (String)groupmap.get(GROUP);
        Log.d("LocalListFragment", "onChildClick c="+c+" g="+g);

        return false;
    }
```

it seems to work well

FYI,

```
private static final String GROUP = "GROUP";
    private static final String CHILD = "CHILD";
```

are used when creating the maps like this curGroupMap.put(GROUP, "GROUP" + i);